# Different ways of naming functions?

Tags: javascript, function, naming

In Javascript what is the difference between:

`var name = function() { //stuff to do };`

`{name : function() { //stuff to do } };`

`function name() { //stuff to do };`

Comment: Is that `javascript`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written by Stoyan Stefanov in ["JavaScript Patterns"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752):

> In function declarations and named function expressions, the name
>   property is defined. In anonymous function expressions, it depends on
>   the implementation; it could be undefined (IE) or defined with an
>   empty string (Firefox, WebKit):
>
> ```
> function foo() {} // declaration
> var bar = function () {}; // expression
> var baz = function baz() {}; // named expression
>
> foo.name; // "foo"
> bar.name; // ""
> baz.name; // "baz"
> ```
>
> The name property is useful when debugging code in Firebug or other
>   debuggers. When the debugger needs to show you an error in a function,
>   it can check for the presence of the name property and use it as an
>   indicator. The name property is also used to call the same function
>   recursively from within itself. If you were not interested in these
>   two cases, then an unnamed function expression would be easier and
>   less verbose.
>
> The case against function declarations and the reason to prefer
>   function expressions is that the expressions highlight that functions
>   are objects like all other objects and not some special language
>   construct.